# Getting Stack Overflow Error on Running the Following Merge Sort Program in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

My code in java for performing merge sort is as follows, but unable to find the bug in the code which results in an Stack Overflow error at the line 'left=mergeSort(left);'. What is the reason for this error, the error is probably because of the infinite recursion but i am unable to find what i am missing.

```
import java.util.*;


public class MergeSort {
public static int[] mergeSort(int [] arr)
{
    int n=arr.length;
    int[] left;
    int[] right;
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        left=new int[n/2];
        right=new int[n/2];

    }
    else
    {
        left=new int[n/2];
        right=new int[n/2+1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i<n/2)
        {
        left[i]=arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            right[i-n/2]=arr[i];
        }

    }

    left=mergeSort(left);
    right=mergeSort(right);
    return merge(left,right);
}

public static int[] merge(int[] left,int[] right)
{
    int[] result=new int[left.length+right.length];

    int index=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<left.length&&j<right.length)
    {
        if(left[i]<right[j])
        {
            result[index++]=left[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            result[index++]=right[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<left.length)
    {
        result[index++]=left[i++];
    }
    while(j<right.length)
    {
        result[index++]=right[j++];
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] list={4,9,7,6,3,1,2};
    mergeSort(list);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list));

}
}
```

Comment: what if n=1 then `left = new int[0]`? have you had stop condition of recursive function yet?

Comment: You need a stop clause at the beginning of mergeSort function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re calling mergeSort recursively, but at the beginning you don’t check for your base case to return, so you have an infinite recursive loop. What condition would indicate that you’re done? Test for that at the beginning of mergeSort().

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, i missed the condition to return the merged array and so I have included the if condition for the recursive call, which will call the function only if the length of the passed array is greater than 1. So the updated code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MergeSort {
public static int[] mergeSort(int [] arr)
{
    int n=arr.length;
    int[] left;
    int[] right;
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        left=new int[n/2];
        right=new int[n/2];

    }
    else
    {
        left=new int[n/2];
        right=new int[n/2+1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i<n/2)
        {
        left[i]=arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            right[i-n/2]=arr[i];
        }

    }


    if(n>1)
    {
    left=mergeSort(left);
    right=mergeSort(right);
    }

    return merge(left,right);

}

public static int[] merge(int[] left,int[] right)
{
    int[] result=new int[left.length+right.length];

    int index=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<left.length&&j<right.length)
    {
        if(left[i]<right[j])
        {
            result[index++]=left[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            result[index++]=right[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<left.length)
    {
        result[index++]=left[i++];
    }
    while(j<right.length)
    {
        result[index++]=right[j++];
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] list={4,9,7,6,3,1,2};
    int[] arr=mergeSort(list);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));

}
}
```

Comment: This is not best practice for recursion. Testing for the base case should always be step #1 in a recursive method.

Comment: How would u make the changes to code if testing for the base case should be the step#1?

Comment: The first line of mergeSort() should be if(arr.length <= 1) return;

Comment: Then get rid of your if (n > 1) test at the end

Comment: Oops, sorry, the first line should be: if(arr.length <= 1) return arr;